# Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object

Tags: java, android

Не могу передать Object из одного Activity в другое. Нужно передать Menu, в котором содержится MenuElement оба реализуются Serializable.
В MainActivity:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();

    Menu menu = new Menu();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectorActivity.class);
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.cafeMenuButton:
            MenuElement me1 = new MenuElement(this, R.drawable.wrx1);
            MenuElement me2 = new MenuElement(this, R.drawable.sky2);
            MenuElement me3 = new MenuElement(this, R.drawable.sky3);
            menu.push(me1);
            menu.push(me2);
            menu.push(me3);
            intent.putExtra("menu", menu);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

В SelectorActivity:

```
public class SelectorActivity extends Activity {


    private Menu menu;
    private TableLayout table;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) throws NullPointerException{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selector);

        table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.selectorTable);
        menu = new Menu();
        menu = (Menu) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("menu");
        menuMarkup();
    }

    private void menuMarkup(){
        int columns = menu.getColumns();
        int menuElementsLenght = menu.getElementsLenght();

        for (int i = 0; i < menuElementsLenght; i++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                 MenuElement view = menu.getElementMenu(i);
                 view.setBackgroundResource(view.getIcon());
                 tr.addView(view);
            }
            table.addView(tr);
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка в строке

> menu = (Menu) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("menu");

Logcat:

```
imenu.interactivemenu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: imenu.interactivemenu, PID: 15952
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{imenu.interactivemenu/imenu.interactivemenu.SelectorActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = imenu.interactivemenu.Menu)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5589)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = imenu.interactivemenu.Menu)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2374)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2197)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
                                                                       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                                                       at android.os.BaseBundle.getSerializable(BaseBundle.java:988)
                                                                       at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:894)
                                                                       at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:5200)
                                                                       at imenu.interactivemenu.SelectorActivity.onCreate(SelectorActivity.java:24)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5993)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:168) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5589) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751) 
                                                                    Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: android.view.View; IllegalAccessException
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.resolveConstructorClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:735)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:673)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:454)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2372)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2197) 
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479) 
                                                                       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
                                                                       at android.os.BaseBundle.getSerializable(BaseBundle.java:988) 
                                                                       at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:894) 
                                                                       at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:5200) 
                                                                       at imenu.interactivemenu.SelectorActivity.onCreate(SelectorActivity.java:24) 
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5993) 
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:168) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5589) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

Comment: Извиняюсь что logcat отформатировался не правильно

Comment: У вас в конструктор MenuElement контекст передаётся? Если да, то его сериализовать в принципе невозможно.